# When combining the BSP library and std::vector, I cannot send data between cores

Tags: c++, parallel-processing

I am using the BSP library to make a parallel program. As some point I declare some

```
std::vector<size_t> segmentPrimes
```

on each core and fill them as the program runs. Then I want to aggregate all those vectors in one long vector on core 0 (the first core). However, this does not work for some reason. The

```
bsp_put
```

command does not function properly here for some reason or I am messing something up. Here is a simple MWE of my problem

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
extern "C" {
#include <mcbsp.h>
}


using namespace std;
int main(){
  bsp_begin(4); // start parallel part with 4 cores
  vector<size_t> segmentPrimes; 
  unsigned long core = bsp_pid(); // gives id number of the current core

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    segmentPrimes.push_back(i + 10*core); // each vector initialized to something illustrative 
  if (core == 0)
    segmentPrimes.resize(4*10,0); // make the vector in core 0 larger 

  bsp_push_reg(&segmentPrimes,segmentPrimes.size()*sizeof(size_t)); // register the vectors
  bsp_sync();

  for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++){
    if (core == i) // each core sends their vector to part of the vector in core 0
      bsp_put(0,&segmentPrimes,&segmentPrimes,(i*10)*sizeof(size_t),10*sizeof(size_t));
    bsp_sync();
  }

  if (core == 0) // print the resulting vector on core 0
    for (int i = 0; i < segmentPrimes.size(); i++)
      cout << segmentPrimes[i]; 

  bsp_end(); // finish parallel part

  return 0;
}
```

Can anyone identify what the problem is? I do not get any error messages but the output it as follows

```
0123456789000000000000000000000000000000
```

while the numbers should be ever increasing. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Btw, I compile with the command

```
g++ FILENAME.cpp -L../bsp/lib -lmcbsp1.2.0 -lpthread
```

EDIT. For those interested, the working core

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
extern "C" {
#include <mcbsp.h>
}


using namespace std;
int main(){
  bsp_begin(4); // start parallel part with 4 cores
  vector<size_t> segmentPrimes; 
  unsigned long core = bsp_pid(); // gives id number of the current core

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    segmentPrimes.push_back(i + 10*core); // each vector initialized to something illustrative 
  if (core == 0)
    segmentPrimes.resize(4*10,0); // make the vector in core 0 larger 

  bsp_push_reg(&(segmentPrimes[0]),segmentPrimes.size()*sizeof(size_t)); // register the vectors
  bsp_sync();

  for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++){
    if (core == i) // each core sends their vector to part of the vector in core 0
      bsp_put(0,&(segmentPrimes[0]),&(segmentPrimes[0]),(i*10)*sizeof(size_t),10*sizeof(size_t));
    bsp_sync();
  }

  if (core == 0) // print the resulting vector on core 0
    for (int i = 0; i < segmentPrimes.size(); i++)
      cout << segmentPrimes[i] << "\t";

  bsp_end(); // finish parallel part

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vectors in C++ doesn't behave like arrays. Internally they have a pointer pointing to where the data is. So, sending this:

```
bsp_put(0,&segmentPrimes,&segmentPrimes,(i*10)*sizeof(size_t),10*sizeof(size_t));
```

won't ever send the data. Is like sending a pointer, but not its content.

Use an array instead.

## Forced to use vector

If you are somehow forced to use a Vector, you can:

- Since C++11 use segmentPrimes.data() instead of &segmentPrimes.
- Use &segmentPrimes[0] instead of &segmentPrimes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I wish I could but we cannot simply change the entire program. I got it to work just . I will update the question

Comment: Yeah I figured. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: I edited if you are forced to use vector instead of array, so you can work without changing the entire program.